# Add some text on result of MySQL Case Operator

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-builder

How I can add some text on result of MySQL Case Operator?

I would like to get some result like this:

```
<a href="/job/234/php-developer"></a>
```

I try this but get a error syntax:

```
SELECT (CASE
  WHEN job_url_outside IS NULL 
    THEN '<a href="/job/', job_id, '/', job_url, '"></a>' 
    ELSE '<a href="', job_url_outside, '" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a>' 
    END) AS job_url 
  FROM job
```

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: Error in query (1064): Syntax error near ' job_id, '/', job_url, '"></a>' ELSE '<a href="', job_url_outside, '" target="_b' at line 1

Comment: ...probably the MySQL server does not know how to handle all these comma seperated values. Have a look at the documentation about how to use `CASE`

Comment: And, for your next question: please always add such an error message to the question, not to the comment section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you want to concatenate some strings? Then use the following query, where `CONCAT` is added to do the concatenation:

```
SELECT (CASE
  WHEN job_url_outside IS NULL 
    THEN CONCAT('<a href="/job/', job_id, '/', job_url, '"></a>') 
    ELSE CONCAT('<a href="', job_url_outside, '" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a>') 
    END) AS job_url 
  FROM job
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
CONCAT(column,'some text',column)
```

More information [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php)

In your case it will be like this:

```
SELECT (CASE
  WHEN job_url_outside IS NULL 
    THEN CONCAT('<a href="/job/', job_id, '/', job_url, '"></a>') 
    ELSE CONCAT('<a href="', job_url_outside, '" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a>') 
    END) AS job_url 
  FROM job;
```

**DEMO** [here](http://rextester.com/TWSP1333)

Answer (score 0):

You should string concatenate the href string together.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN job_url_outside IS NULL THEN '<a href="/job/' + job_id + '/' + job_url + '"></a>' ELSE '<a href="' + job_url_outside + '" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a>' END) AS job_url FROM job
```